# Control 2 LEDs with ECU pin

Tags: current

For a car project I’m looking for a way to control 2 LEDs with 1 ecu pin.

In the current situation, the ECU output pin delivers 12V, and inside the ECU either a 1k or 2k resistor is used to control the output current. So the ECU can switch between the 2 values.

A LES is connected to the output pin, and depending on the ECU state, the LED is getting 6mA by the 2k resistor, or 12mA by the 1k resitor.

In the first situation the LED will glow slightly, in the second state it will be brighter.

Now my plan is to replace the 1 LED design by a 2 LED configuration.

Is there a way to control 2 leds (1 turning on when the output is 6mA and the other when the output is 12mA?
This by only using the ECU output signal and ground? So without using a connection to the battery?

Comment: Have you considered using the pin output to control a relay?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried. But the current is to low to switch the relay. 
There is also a big hysteresis on a mechanical relay. So switching between 2 positions based on input current didnt work

Comment: Without using a connection to the battery or a reliable source of a steady voltage I think you may be scuppered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do the job. You need LEDs that can produce a decent amount of light from 4mA in order to leave enough current to run the rest of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY4XI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful. 
I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky designing a circuit that works well when there is a high resistance (1K or 2K ohms) in its supply line; most ICs are designed to work with a stabilised supply, and could behave quite unpredictably when given such a high impedance - I'm not sure that the common simulation tools can accurately model the effects of a wobbly supply on an op-amp or comparator.

Here is my design using a simpler device: the TL431 'programmable zener'. It basically acts as an NPN transistor, with a sharp off-to-on transition when the control voltage hits 2.5V. The on-voltage between the anode and cathode is around 2V.

[image: Test circuit]

If the circuit powers up with 2K in series with 12V, then Q1 is turned on via R3, D2 and R2. This lights up D1, with a current of (12 - 0.3 - 2.1) / (2000 + 560) = 3.75 mA, assuming the LED forward voltage is 2.1, and the VCEsat of the transistor is 0.3V; almost any NPN transistor will do.

At this current, the input voltage will have dropped to 12 - (0.00375 * 2000) = 4.5V

When the input resistor drops from 2K to 1K, the current through D1 rises to (12 - 0.3 - 2.1) / (1000 + 560) = 6.15 mA, which means the input voltage is 12 - (0.00615 * 1000) = 5.85 V.

Resistors R4 and R5 have been chosen so this puts more than 2.5 V on the control pin of D3, so it conducts current through R3 and D2, and shuts of the base current of Q1, which turns off. The current through D2 is (12 - 2.1 - 2.0) / (1000 + 560) = 5.1 mA, which means a supply voltage of 12 - (0.0051 * 1000)  = 6.9 V

So LED D1 should be lit when there is a 2K resistor in the supply line; D2 should light instead when the resistance drops to 1K.

This leaves a couple of problems; during the switch-over, both LEDs will be on very briefly, which may cause oscillation, so a small capacitor between input & ground might be needed to hold up the supply voltage during the transition; I'd start by trying 10 uF.

The other problem is that a 12V vehicle supply isn't really 12V, it goes up to 14.4V when an alternator is charging the battery, so the calculations need to be checked with an increased voltage.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will order the parts and do some testing with it to see if it works. Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helps when being a beginner like me . 

On another forum I got these 2 schematics, so will give them a try as well to see which one works best for my application. 

[schematic1](https://postimg.cc/62HNMPjR). 

[schematic2](https://postimg.cc/rRK2393H)

Comment: If you can afford the time to test them, it'd be interesting to see which of these designs works out best in practice, when considering the wide range of supply voltages that occur on a vehicle. Looking at my design in the cold light of day, I'd probably bump up R4 and R5 to 22K each, to reduce the loading on the input voltage, but it really needs a proper simulation, as my calculations do use some short-cuts for simplicity.